# Free .exe for coordinate transformation lat-long - UTM

Tags: coordinate-system

I need to find a simple program for Windows which transforms lat-long to UTM. I know that there a websites to do this, but this is for use with the emergency services. The forestry commision use gps hardware which gives coordinates in Lat-Long. The software back in the Emergency central have to use UTM. The software doesn´t transform coordinates. They have asked me to find a solution to do a quick conversion. I wouldn´t like to put lives at risk by using a website which could go offline just when we need it, so I would prefer an installed program. Any good ones out there?

Comment: Is it a nation wide service so that you can't use a fixed UTM zone but the program should recognize it first?

Comment: Will not be nation wide...just for a small regional emergency service. UTM Zone 32 only

Comment: What about programming the GPS to have UTM coordinates instead of WGS84 ? It would save you a conversion.

Comment: Here is python code for a world wide converter http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Do-we-have-to-know-UTM-zone-a-priori-to-convert-to-UTM-from-lat-lon-td3743625.html

Comment: this seems to be ready to use http://download.cnet.com/UTM-Coordinate-Converter/3000-12940_4-75961066.html

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I can´t change the gps hardware as they are administered by another authority. I cannot install any python or database applications as I simply don´t have the time. I was after a simple exe to install on the desktops of the emergency PCs so the workers can do a quick conversion.

Comment: Are the lat-long values in decimal degrees or DMS or DD MM.mmm? If the latter, that might mean a different solution. US NGS has a UTMS tool, but it wants HDDMMSS.sss. Other possibilities are CORPSCON or GEOTRANS for GUI-based solutions.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of potential solutions.

You could use QGIS or install Proj4 and GDAL and write a little script.

If you have PostGIS or some other free geospatial database, that would do too (SpatiaLite is lightwieght and could do the job).

Comment: I was hoping to not have to spend any time programming. I just need a simple exe.

Comment: Then use QGIS - no programming needed

Comment: To install QGIS for a simple coordinate transformation in text form is a bit too complicated for the user. I just want to transform a pair of text coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

You can use for example the "gdaltransform" utility http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html

Usage for EPSG:32632 (is this right?)

WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N

<32632> +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  <>

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:32632
6.12 20.32  #input as lon lat
199253.644766105 2249519.51282395 0
```